# Reduction kernel call from Single-Source in RenderScript

Tags: android, renderscript, reduction, single-source

I implemented an algorithm in Single-Source. Now, I want to decrease my algorithm's processing time with reduction.

Can reduction kernels be called from Single-Source in RenderScript?

Comment: I honestly can't tell what is mean by "Single-Source". Can you improve your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49090927/edit) it with additional information about what algorithm you are trying to accomplish and what you've tried to improve performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.  From the Renderscript documentation (bold is mine):

> Android 7.0 (API level 24) introduces a new programming feature called Single-Source RenderScript, in which kernels are launched from the script where they are defined, rather than from Java. **This approach is currently limited to mapping kernels**, which are simply referred to as "kernels" in this section for conciseness.

However, I think you may also be confused about what a reduction kernel is.  A reduction kernel is one which takes an input `Allocation` and outputs a single value (such as a minimum or maximum, the sum, etc.)  It is not the same as optimizing your kernel, which is what it sounds like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't, I'm sorry.